# DocuSign Impersonation indicator in API call

Tags: docusignapi

Do we have the privilege to access the indicator which tells us if the newly user created in DocuSign has confirmed the impersonation consent.

We have a requirement where we will refrain the user to send envelopes until the consent is being completed by him.
Need a flag to know that via API call. I could see we have 'UserInformation' object  however was unable to find the appropriate flag for that.
Your response would be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance!
Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can attempt to create a DocuSign access token for the user via the JWT grant flow. If you succeed then you know that the user granted impersonation consent.

If you get a `consent required` error then you know that the impersonation consent has not yet been granted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the thing is I am expecting some flag that would tell me upfront whether the consent is granted or not from some userful object from DocuSign API. If the flag is not available, the last thing would be to try create an envelope and handle the consent required error in the backend and delegate the same to  UI as you mentioned in your reply.

Comment: Sorry, there is no API call as you propose. Note that requesting an access token (and using that flow to determine consent) is not the same as creating an envelope. Creating an envelope is a separate API call that needs an access token.